# Why a simple button in WP Metabox saves the post?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I've created a new metabox in my plugin and I've added a button to it.
If I click on the button in the metabox, Javascript redirects me to  "post.php?post=30&action=edit&message=4", it's a simple button without JS functions!

This is the code:

```
function create_metaboxes() {
add_meta_box('wc-price', 'WooCommerce Price Calculator', 'metaboxes_html', 'product');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'create_metaboxes');

function metaboxes_html($post) {
    wp_nonce_field("price_nonce", "price-calculator", false, false); 
    // echo '<div class="full al-right">';
    echo '<button class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-       hidden="true"></span> Aggiungi colore</button>';
    // echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! :)
I've used this code in my Javascript file:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('button').click( function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    } );
});
```